# When can we talk to the moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, chat

Chat is really useful for discussing anything related to the site that isn't a good fit for comments, questions, or the meta.  However, there's not always a moderator available to answer my questions and have a conversation.  When can I be sure I can talk to one?

Answer (score 4):

We're going to start doing Office Hours.  If you keep an eye on the chat room's [schedule](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3748/the-bakery?tab=schedule), you'll be able to see when at least one moderator will guarantee availability.  This **does not mean we're not around during other times**.  If you'd like to get our attention, you can always [tag us](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications) and if we're on the site, we'll see that someone wants to talk in chat.

However, we'd really like to make sure if you have any questions, suggestions, or want to talk about anything you know you'll be able to.  You will also be able to see the events in the [community bulliten](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129483/181389).